# Oraclize parity error

Tags: solidity, parity, oracles

I have a contract in Remix which runs perfectly on the Ethereum Ropsten Test net.

I now want to deploy the contractin the main ethereum net using parity. When I click to deploy the contract in parity and copy-paste the code from remix to parity I get the attached error.

I have some questions:

1) If I continue the deployment of the contract Oraclize functions will work fine at the main net?
2) If not how can I import the oraclize file in parity?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

There must be something stopping geth from retrieving the contract from the github source.

Instead, you can manually copy and paste the `oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol` contract [from here](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol) into your file, above your own contract. Then remove the `import "github.com/...;` line and it'll deploy & work correctly.